# How do I use dynamic parameters with autofac's RegisterGeneric() method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, autofac

**Current situation**

I am registering some classes, one-by-one, all with the following pattern:

```
builder.RegisterType<NpgsqlDapperRepository<Foo, int>>()
                .As<IDapperRepository<Foo, int>>()
                .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("connectionString", ConnectionString))
                .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("tableName", "Foos"))
                .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("schema", "dbo"))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

**What I am attempting**

I want to use `RegisterGeneric()` as follows:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(NpgsqlDapperRepository<,>))
                .As(typeof(IDapperRepository<,>))
                .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("connectionString", ConnectionString))
                .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("tableName", ???)) //TODO: Determine table name from entity type (acquire from dictionary or something). How do I acquire the type?
                .WithParameter(new NamedParameter("schema", "dbo"))
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Obviously this is so I don't need to register 100s of entities which essentially have the exact same configuration with just 1 parameter being different.

**The problem**

I need to determine the table name from the entity type. How do I acquire the type when using `RegisterGeneric()`? Is this even possible?

**Extra note**

I noticed something called `ResolvedParameter` and looked into that, but I'm not sure if it's what I need. I am thinking not. However, if that is indeed what I need, I would appreciate an example for my situation.

Comment: Take a look at the `log4net` logger resolution code, it seems to be similar to what you want. See if you can adapt it for your use... http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `Parameter`

```
public class TableNameParameter : Parameter
{
    public override Boolean CanSupplyValue(
        ParameterInfo pi, IComponentContext context, out Func<Object> valueProvider)
    {
        valueProvider = null;

        if (pi.ParameterType != typeof(String) && pi.Name != "tableName")
            return false;

        valueProvider = () =>
        {
            ITableNameResolver tableNameResolver = context.Resolve<ITableNameResolver>();
            Type entityType = pi.Member.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            String tableName = tableNameResolver.GetTableName(entityType);
            return tableName;
        };
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!